# UIButton Highlight not working in Custom Table View Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I created a custom tableview cell and there is a button.
When I click the button, the button didn't highlight. This project is written with swift 3 and based on iOS 10. Need your help right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just fixed this problem.
UITableView inherits from UIScrollView and should set delaysContentTouch to false.
It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom Button type. For that, in your interface builder, set button type to custom from system.

Comment: This needs a lot of work for a simple work. not acceptable.

Comment: u simply want to highlight color of button or you want to listen action of button?

Comment: highlight color of button.